# extracting element from array (bash)

Tags: linux, arrays, bash

I'm having trouble extracting specific elements from an array. Basically I used the output from a command and put it into an array. I would like to print out one element.

Here's my code so far.

```
one=`w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1 | tail -n+3`
two=`w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f5 | tail -n+3`
echo ${one[@]:3:2}
```

This will only print out two letters starting from the third letter in the name. I want to print out two names starting from the third name.

Comment: You know that all-caps is considered offensive, right? Also its harder to read than regular sentence-casing, because humans read by interpreting the *shape* of words.

Comment: Reference for the above: [The Science of Word Recognition, or how I learned to stop worrying and love the bouma](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ctfonts/wordrecognition.aspx).

Comment: Golly! I had no idea people were offended by all-caps! My life is better now because of it. Thank you for improving the internet @ DAVID THOMAS. I'm sorry I hindered your ability to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create `one` and `two` as arrays if you want to use them as arrays.

```
one=($(w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1 | tail -n+3))
```

Also, bash arrays are indexed starting from 0. So, to print out two names starting from `third` name, you will use

```
echo ${one[@]:2:2}
```

Comment: This does not address the problem that I stated. It will only print out the letters and not the entire name

Comment: I thought it did. I checked it on my system before posting here. Did you try this. Can you show a sample usage where its not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- the initialisation of the arrays should be as follows:

  `one=($(w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1 | tail -n+3))`
- then to print the elements you should do:

  `echo ${one[1]} ${one[2]}`

Comment: This does not address the problem that I stated. It will only print out the letters and not the entire name

Comment: um - no, it prints out the second and third user name. if you want the third and fourth name use ${one[2]} ${one[3]}